# Cannot see browser actions while running automation test from MTM

Tags: bdd, specflow, mtm

I am executing my automation tests from MTM, and they are getting successfully passed or failed. But can i see the live session of execution while i run my tests from MTM or Am i approaching this wrong?

I have already setup Controller and one agent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Login to the test agent where you are running the test case and you will be able to see all the actions. Just make sure to follow the golden rule of running coded ui automation "Sit on your hand while you are running the test case", don't interact with the test agent machine.